# How to install for ALL users on a Mac

Tags: installation

I need to install Blender for multiple users on a mac, but they do not have admin permissions to install themselves. I need to be able to install under my admin account for all standard users as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't use a Mac, but I think this question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312058/do-applications-install-for-all-users-or-only-for-one) answers it.

> It depends where it installs to.
>
> If it goes into the main Applications folder, then yes, it's available
>   to all users - though each user will have their own distinct prefs,
>   saved under their account.
>
> If it's installed to /Users/[your name]/Applications, then it's only
>   available to that user

This [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5403545) also seems relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue since 2.8x I believe where the default file mode/permissions were incorrect:

https://developer.blender.org/T72605

Suggested workaround until this is fixed is to set the mode to 755.  This will allow it to be read and executed by other users besides the owner.  Assuming you installed into the default location:

```
find /Applications/Blender.app -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Might be overkill, use at your own discretion.

Answer (score 0):

I use school macs all the time. Like @stphnl329 said, if you are installing blender into the applications folder, you will need an admin password. Though, I would get away with opening blender from the .dmg without a password. I would also be able to copy the program from the dmg and paste it onto the desktop so I could open it from there as well.

This may be helpful to some extent.